# Extract strings after different occurences of a char

Tags: javascript

I have a array of strings which contain something similar to:

```
array[0]=Name: Bob Last: Jones Age: 36
array[1]=Name: James Last: Brown Age: 29
array[2]=Name: Lloyd Last: Mals Age: 45
```

I want to get the name of each and place them in seperate arrays

Like the following:

```
name[0]=Bob
last[0]=Jones
age[0]=36

name[1]=James
last[1]=Brown
age[1]=29

name[2]=Lloyd
last[2]=Mals
age[2]=45
```

How do I do this in Javascript?

Comment: Hint: `'Name: Bob Last: Jones Age: 36'.split(' ');` gives `["Name:", "Bob", "Last:", "Jones", "Age:", "36"]`

Comment: That wouldnt intrest me much..........I would just need those 3 values from the string......I would need to split from the '  ' and then from the ':'....Would it be possible?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you could do this, but here is an example using regular expressions.

To get an array of values from each string you could use `split`

```
str = 'Name: Bob Last: Jones Age: 36';
values = str.split( /\s?\w+:\s/ );         // [ "", "Bob", "Jones", "36" ]
```

or, to avoid the initial empty string you could use `match`

```
values = str.match( /\w+(?=\s\w+:|$)/g );  // [ "Bob", "Jones", "36" ]
```

To learn more about regular expressions see [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html).